# Redundant Power System integration

Tags: electrical-power, power-supply-unit

We currently have a stack of catalyst 3750's at the core of our network. We just purchased two new 3750's to split off our VMs and SAN onto their own switches and away from the stack.

These two new switches will not be stacked. All switches are also plugged into the same redundant power system... I cannot seem to find a direct answer to this question-

Must we bring down the whole network and power down the redundant power system when integrating and plugging these new switches in to the RPS? Or- can we simply plug the new switches into the RPS while everything is up and running?

Comment: [Cisco RPS system](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/routers/access/rps/hardware/installation/guide/rps4.html) for clarification.

Answer (score 4):

3750's unfortunately need to reboot between RPS transitions sorry, found this out the hard way myself a few years back.

Comment: What happened when you did not take down the other switches when adding the new ones?

Comment: They were fine, it was the newly-added ones we assumed were ok, but weren't.

Comment: So if I understand you, the newly added switches must be rebooted after being hooked up to RPS while the existing switches are OK to remain up? Thank you for your insight

Comment: Yes, you need to bounce the newly connected ones before the RPS will work right but the existing ones will remain fine if they've been rebooted previously ok :)

Comment: Wow Cisco... just wow.

Answer (score 1):

"Note: If you want to connect an additional external device to a Cisco RPS that is already 
powered up, you can do so without interrupting power to the Cisco RPS or any 
other connected external devices. Be sure to connect your cable to the Cisco RPS 
first and then to the external device. However, in a redundant-with-reboot 
configuration, to ensure proper operation, you must power up the switch or hub 
before powering up the Cisco RPS. Therefore, always connect the switch to AC 
power before you connect it to the Cisco RPS. Failure to follow the proper 
power-up sequence can result in incorrect LED displays."

-Cisco Documentation